# how to reload routes /config/routes/* in rails 4?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4, reload

How to force rails 4 to reload all route files?
***That is without having to restart the application to make the routes from /config/routes/*.rb get loaded***
I did a split them up in /config/routes/*.rb
but these /config/routes/* files are not reloaded.

This worked in rails 3 but not 4:

```
#config.paths['config/routes'].unshift *Dir["config/routes/*.rb"]
```

Comment: In my Rails 3 project, your code example indeed loads routes from those files, but it does not seem to reload them in development – I need to restart the server to pick up changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
Rails.application.reload_routes!
```

You can [read about it here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) (will have to use `find`)

Answer (score 6):

```
config.paths["config/routes.rb"] << YOUR_ROUTE_FILE
```

Comment: With a directory of routes (as opposed to a single one per above), `+=` didn't work, but this did: `Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")].sort.each { |route_file| config.paths["config/routes.rb"] << route_file }` Work in the sense that I no longer get an error message. No idea about whether they reload without restarting the app. Probably not.

Comment: We use `config.paths` in Rails 4 to have multiple route files, everything is reloaded fine in production.

Answer (score -1):

In Rails 3, if you are splitting the `routes.rb` file into multiple files, we have to add this line to application.rb:

```
config.paths['config/routes'].concat Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]
```

...and the corresponding routes in `config/routes/*.rb` files
like this:

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :test
  end
end
```

In Rails 4, Rails no longer provides a `["config/routes"]` key in `Rails::Engine.paths`. However, in Rails 4, there is no need to add to `config.path` in `application.rb`.

Just add the corresponding routes under `config/routes/*.rb`.

Comment: It requires restart of Rails application on every change to /config/routes/*.rb file, changes to /config/routes.rb do work. But my question was aiming towards reloading the /config/routes/*.rb file modifications without a restart. Like you suggest is not true it does not reload by itself!