# rails 5 dynamic routing redirections based on model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following resources

`Places (:place_id, :name, :shortlink, :token)`

`Events (:event_id, :address)`

I have a restricted user registration with a nested user resource (User has many Events).

When User register, (s)he create a new event with a referenced place column.

Users can only sign up when having theses parameters in the url

https://mysite/user/signup?q=[:place_id]&t=[:token] # place id must exist, place token must be equal to t parameter

```
before_action :check_has_access, only: [:new]
...
protected

def check_has_access
  @place = Place.find(params[:q])
   if params[:q].blank? && @place.blank? || params[:t].blank? || @place.token != params[:t]
     redirect_to(root_path)
     flash[:alert] = 'Restricted sign-up'
   end
end
```

I want to generate a shortcut for each place for the user to register

https://mysite/[:shortlink] #place.shortlink

That will redirect to a given sign up form with corresponding filled form and restricted params so the user that has the direct url can sign up.

https://mysite/user/signup?q=[:place_id]&t=[:token]

How can I have routes to be generated ?

Subsidiary question, am I doing it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316969/rails-routes-base-on-model-attributes).

I need to restart the server so newly created route get loaded after a Place object creation. Not sure if I am doing it right though but it works..

```
#config/route.rb

 Rails.application.routes.draw do
    Place.all.each do |pl|
         get "/#{pl.shortlink}" => redirect("/users/sign_up?q=#{pl.id}&t=#{pl.token}")
       end
    end
```

In order to [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902878/how-to-reload-routes-config-routes-in-rails-4) the newly created route when adding a Place, I added

```
#models/place.rb

after_create :add_shortlink
...
  def add_shortlink
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

This will not work on Heroku, issue addressed is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236619/dynamic-rails-routes-based-on-database-models)